# [Laravel][php]how to make a function who will loss number once a day

Tags: php, algorithm, laravel, laravel-5

I was making a electronic diary for schools. But I must make a function which will loss random number only once a day. I know how to loss a number, but I dont know how to loss a number automatically once a day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) for that:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        // Do seomthing each day
    })->daily();
}
```